# Is it possible to transfer authentication from Webbrowser to WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control, webclient

I'm using webbrowser control to login any site. And then i want to download some sub page html using WebRequest (or WebClient). This links must requires authentication.

How to transfer Webbrowser authentication information to Webrequest or Webclient?

Comment: From the names of the classes can one assume you are asking about the .NET base class library classes?

Comment: What kind of authentication do the links require?  A login form?  SSL client certificate?  Windows authentication?

Comment: Can you please take a step back and describe what exactly you are doing? Can you make changes to the website? Is it an external website that is hosting your control? What does the control need from the website for which it has to do authentication?

Answer (score 45):

If the question is only "How to transfer Webbrowser authentication information to Webrequest or Webclient?" this code is enough:

You can call the GetUriCookieContainer method that returns you a CookieContainer that can be used for subsequent call with WebRequest object.

```
  [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(
        string url, 
        string cookieName, 
        StringBuilder cookieData, 
        ref int size,
        Int32  dwFlags,
        IntPtr  lpReserved);

    private const Int32 InternetCookieHttponly = 0x2000;

/// <summary>
/// Gets the URI cookie container.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">The URI.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static CookieContainer GetUriCookieContainer(Uri uri)
{
    CookieContainer cookies = null;
    // Determine the size of the cookie
    int datasize = 8192 * 16;
    StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
    if (!InternetGetCookieEx(uri.ToString(), null, cookieData, ref datasize, InternetCookieHttponly, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        if (datasize < 0)
            return null;
        // Allocate stringbuilder large enough to hold the cookie
        cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
        if (!InternetGetCookieEx(
            uri.ToString(),
            null, cookieData, 
            ref datasize, 
            InternetCookieHttponly, 
            IntPtr.Zero))
            return null;
    }
    if (cookieData.Length > 0)
    {
        cookies = new CookieContainer();
        cookies.SetCookies(uri, cookieData.ToString().Replace(';', ','));
    }
    return cookies;
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't include "Secure" cookies by default. To get those you would just need to pass in a URI beginning with https instead of http.

Comment: Actually, I dont have any Idea where to put or use this code, could you help with that ?

Comment: you can put this code in any source code file you want, it is a simple helper method to ask to operating system all cookies for a specific Uri you pass as argument.

Answer (score 10):

If found this solution. Simple create a Class.cs file with the information below and call the static `GetCookieInternal` function.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


internal sealed class NativeMethods
{
    #region enums

    public enum ErrorFlags
    {
        ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122,
        ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87,
        ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
    }

    public enum InternetFlags
    {
        INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 8192, //Requires IE 8 or higher   
        INTERNET_COOKIE_THIRD_PARTY = 131072,
        INTERNET_FLAG_RESTRICTED_ZONE = 16
    }

    #endregion

    #region DLL Imports

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, SecurityCritical, DllImport("wininet.dll", EntryPoint = "InternetGetCookieExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx([In] string Url, [In] string cookieName, [Out] StringBuilder cookieData, [In, Out] ref uint pchCookieData, uint flags, IntPtr reserved);

    #endregion
}


/// <SUMMARY></SUMMARY>   
/// WebBrowserCookie?   
/// webBrowser1.Document.CookieHttpOnlyCookie   
///    
public class FullWebBrowserCookie : WebBrowser
{

    [SecurityCritical]
    public static string GetCookieInternal(Uri uri, bool throwIfNoCookie)
    {
        uint pchCookieData = 0;
        string url = UriToString(uri);
        uint flag = (uint)NativeMethods.InternetFlags.INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY;

        //Gets the size of the string builder   
        if (NativeMethods.InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, null, ref pchCookieData, flag, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            pchCookieData++;
            StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder((int)pchCookieData);

            //Read the cookie   
            if (NativeMethods.InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, cookieData, ref pchCookieData, flag, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                DemandWebPermission(uri);
                return cookieData.ToString();
            }
        }

        int lastErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        if (throwIfNoCookie || (lastErrorCode != (int)NativeMethods.ErrorFlags.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(lastErrorCode);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static void DemandWebPermission(Uri uri)
    {
        string uriString = UriToString(uri);

        if (uri.IsFile)
        {
            string localPath = uri.LocalPath;
            new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, localPath).Demand();
        }
        else
        {
            new WebPermission(NetworkAccess.Connect, uriString).Demand();
        }
    }

    private static string UriToString(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
        }

        UriComponents components = (uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? UriComponents.AbsoluteUri : UriComponents.SerializationInfoString);
        return new StringBuilder(uri.GetComponents(components, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped), 2083).ToString();
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(webBrowser1.Url, false);
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Cookie: " + cookies);
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
byte[] result = wc.UploadData("<URL>", "POST", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData));
```

Comment: This is the only woking solution for me. Parsing page with redirects and SSO.... Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! That's also the only solution that worked for me too. Saved my week!

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to access the cookies of the `WebBrowser` control with `.Document.Cookie` then in your `HTTPWebRequest` you can add that cookie to its cookie container.
Here is an example (VB.NET because I'm most familiar there):

```
Dim browser As New WebBrowser()
/*Do stuff here to auth with your webbrowser and get a cookie.*/

Dim myURL As String = "http://theUrlIWant.com/"
Dim request As New HTTPWebRequest(myURL)
request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
request.CookieContainer.SetCookies(myURL, browser.Document.Cookie)
```

And that should transfer the cookie from your `WebBrowser` control over to your `HTTPWebRequest` class.

Comment: browser.Document.Cookie is null

Comment: Have you connected and authenticated with your web browser control before reading the .Document.Cookie value?

Comment: WebBrowser.Document.Cookie does not contain HttpOnly cookies.

Comment: @JasonHarrison is there a way to get httponly cookie

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta Sorry, I don't kno how to get INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to do this is to get the cookie by using [InternetGetCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384710%28VS.85%29.aspx) function, construct corresponding `cookie` object and use it for the `CookieContainer`

To retrieve HttpOnly cookies use [InternetGetCookieEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384714%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Here are some examples:

[InternetGetCookie() in .NET](http://www.rendelmann.info/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=bd99bcd5-7088-4d46-801e-c0fe622dc2e5)

[Download using Internet Explorer Cookies](http://metasharp.net/index.php/Download_using_Internet_Explorer_Cookies)

Comment: Try InternetGetCookieEx with INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY or INTERNET_COOKIE_THIRD_PARTY

Comment: where is INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY declared?

Answer (score 1):

If you can retrieve the necessary cookies from the WebBrowser control after they are set by the site you are logging into, you should be able to use those same cookies with WebRequest/WebClient.

[This](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html) article outlines how to use cookies with a WebClient; you have to subclass it, but it's only a single override that's needed.

Comment: I'm tring to get cookie. But webbrowser.document.cookie is null

Comment: @ebattulga - if the cookie is 'HttpOnly' then you can't retrieve it from javascript. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A late answer for future references. `WebBrowser` uses [UrlMon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee318402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) library which manages the session per-process, so UrlMon APIs like [URLOpenStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [URLDownloadToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to download any resource on the same session (the APIs can be called from C# via P/invoke). A similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19025793/1768303).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old question but there is answer marked so I want to share the solution I prepared

I have not transferred my cookies from webbrowser to webrequest but I used webclient in place of webrequest and for this there are below steps I followed

Create cookie aware web client
Parse cookies from web browser control
Assign parsed cookies to cookie container
Create cookie aware web client object using cookie container
Use cookie aware web client object to send your requests now

Explained in details on this link http://www.codewithasp.net/2016/06/transferring-cookies-webbrowser-webclient-c-net.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to accomplish what you are trying to do. The server could be using one of two types of authentication with the client (browser)

1) Transport authentication
2) Forms based auth.

Transport auth: In this case, the authentication is done using the transport connection itself - here it will use custom HTTP headers with a multiway handshake to do the auth.

Forms based auth:This is the traditional auth that is done when you enter your credentials into a form.

In either case, the authentication might have already happened by the time your managed control is instantiated. As someone suggested  you can steal the browsers cookies for that domain and use it with webclient but then it may or may not work the way you expect.

If all you want to do is download something, then I would see if I could use the browsers facilities for eg, XmlHttpRequest or some other ajax mechanism to download what you want as part of the DOM of the page that is hosting the control. Then you could read that content from your control, or you could also have the browser inject that content into your control by way of Javascript calling a method/property on your control.

[EDIT]

Find out (using Firebug plugin in firefox) exactly how the forms based auth is being done in the browser. Then you can write code to do exactly the same request/response that the browser is doing. To the website, the client will appear like any other browser based client. Then you should be able to download anything you want from the website.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been through this same problem on the Windows Mobile platform, and the only thing that worked was to extend the WebBrowser control (using C++ :<) to capture the POST/GET vars before the request is sent.

This library may help you out:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx

"..the library implements the PassthroughAPP package by Igor Tandetnik, which enables the client to intercept all HTTP and HTTPS request and responses."

So although it is not possible to get the POST/GET vars used for your basic auth on a standard WebBrowser control, it would be possible if you use an extended control such as the sample I linked - in fact many "Extended WebBrowser" controls are created because of problems very similar to yours.  Unfortunately, as far as I know you need to do this using unmanaged code/c++ :(.