# Authenticate to Google AppEngine application which use federated login from Windows Client Application

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I'm plan on deploy a Java application to Google AppEngine and use federated login (still experimental according to Google). The application is pretty simple Java EE application which expose RESTful interface for simple CRUD operations.

I then want to be able to authenticate to this application using Windows Client Application written in C#.
I think the application should be able to open a window with a browser in ti which will present the login page of my web application and after successful authentication I should be able to get the login token or a cookie to use in the rest of my HTTP requests.

Is it possible to do such thing using federated login? [I've found a post explain how to do it using google proprietary login.](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=894)

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've manage to make this work much easier then I thought it would be.

1. When I send HTTP request to my web service I get 302 Found response with response header name Location which point to the login page.
2. I use WebBrowser control, register to it Navigated even and navigate to the URL in the Location header.
3. When the Navigated even fire I use the code from [this answer to get the cookies container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382498/is-it-possible-to-transfer-authentication-from-webbrowser-to-webrequest/5633826#5633826).
4. I check each cookie until I find one with the name ACSID and store it.
5. For every web request to my service I add cookie name ACSID with the value saved at step 4.

This is not the most secure way of doing this. I will add check for the domain of the cookie but this looks good.