# Convert HttpWebResponse to HttpResponse

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, http, httpresponse

In **C#** or **VB.Net**, there is a way to translate an `HttpWebResponse` object to an `HttpResponse`, or get directlly an `HttpResponse` from a `HttpWebRequest` instance?

Example of what I try to do (it does not work):

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url2), HttpWebRequest)
Dim repsonse As HttpResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your attempting to do something like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(collection) as HttpWebRequest;
if (request != null)
     using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
          using (var writer = File.Create(path))
               stream.CopyTo(writer);
```

That will take the `HttpWebRequest`, then it will build a `Stream`, and will copy the `Stream` to a `FileStream` to write out the contents.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no, sorry, that is not what I mean, but I think I have not clear with my own the concept of what I'm trying to do, just in other question suggested me to use an HttpResponse to try solve a problem, but I can't because I'm using an HttpWebResponse then I thinked to convert the object, please if you can read the comment of @wolfeh in this question it could solve your and my doubt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143651/automate-picture-downloads-from-website-with-authentication

Comment: Ironically, the code I posted is used to build a `collection` of data from an API and download all the pages.