# Very strange behaviour with WebClient.UploadFileASync

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, webclient

I store authentication cookie in to a staic CookieContainer in my application, thanks to the answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382498/is-it-possible-to-transfer-authentication-from-webbrowser-to-webrequest) **(1)**

I implemented the code to get the CookieContainer on `DocumentCompleted` event :

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.webBrowser1.Document.Title.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToLower().Contains("xxx"))
        {
            CookieContainer ck =  GetUriCookieContainer(this.webBrowser1.Url);

            validSession = ck;

            Succeeded = true;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Because I'm using `WebClient`, I need to create an extension of it so it can store CookieContainer :

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    public WebClientEx()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }

    public WebClientEx(CookieContainer c)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = c;
    }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (castRequest != null)
        {
                castRequest.CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```

After storing the CookieContainer from **(1)**, I'm able to request any content of the page without authenticating :

```
        WebClientEx e = new WebClientEx(validSession);
        string x = e.UploadString(new Uri("http://localhost:14590/default.aspx"), "ola");
        // x now contains the html page of default.aspx
```

The problem is when I tried to upload a file to the server using `UploadFileAsync`, I will try to describe the issue step-by-step :

- Open the application
- Open login form (default url will navigate to default.aspx page)
- Login to the website with `WebBrowser` control
- The webBrowser will navigate to default.aspx page
- Store the cookie
- Upload a file using `UploadFileAsync` method
- The result (e.result) on `UploadFileCompleted` event is the login page's html content, meaning the CookieContainer which I passed in WebClient does not work.

But please look at these steps, the Upload function will work without a problem :

- Open the application
- Open login form (default url will navigate to default.aspx page)
- The webBrowser will navigate to default.aspx page
- Store the cookie
- Open login form, now the webBrowser will navigate directly to the default.aspx because the authenticated session is still available.
- Upload a file using `UploadFileAsync` method -> success
- I'm sure the CookieContainer which I get at the first login attempt is correct, because I'm able to use WebClient.UploadString() or any HttpWebRequest to the server with it, by the way I checked the CookieContainer on the second attemp and it's identical to the first.

I can't understand why this is happening? Do you have any ideas why? Please note that If I use other method such as WebClient.UploadString() there's no redirecting back to the login page if the cookieContainer is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reasons, the CookieContainer causes this problem, after watching fiddler, I realize the first call from `webclient` to the server did not contain any cookie, so I get rid of the CookieContainer and replace it with this :

```
    WebClient e = new WebClient();
    e.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookies I get from webbrowser control");
```

And voila, everything is fine!