# Cookie Manipulation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, http, cookies, browser

I'm looking at writing my first WPF application.  Before I begin, I was wondering if it is possible to manipulate an existing browser cookie.

I need to check if a specific cookie exists (I have the cookie name).  If it does exist, I want to modify it's value.

I would appreciate any input.

Comment: WPF is a desktop technology, and has nothing to do with browsers, or cookies.  Are you mistaken in some way?  (Question is akin to asking, "I want to buy a car.  Before I begin, how should I best groom my cat?"

Comment: so...no?  WPF doesn't have any type of browser control?

Comment: Sure WPF does have a browser control, but the WPF controller does not manage the Cookies. You will most likely need to do some reverse engineering to achieve this. Take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975576/managing-cookies-in-a-wpf-webbrowser-control

Comment: Feel free to check:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975576/managing-cookies-in-a-wpf-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 1):

To Set a Cookie:

Uri u = new Uri(@"C:\Paths");

Application.SetCookie(u, file.FileName);

To Get the Value stored in the Cookie:
Uri u = new Uri(@"C:\Paths");
string value = Application.GetCookie(u);