# How to authenticate an HttpClient connection between a WPF application and a web server with an external provider (Google)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, google-api, openid

I have a web server with secured api endpoints - one must have been authenticated with Google prior to using them. I implemented `Challenge` and `Callback` endpoints for that.

This works well from a browser with my SPA web front-end. The user gets redirected to the Google website to sign-in and then gets redirected back to my webapp and it can use the endpoints to update its state.

I also have a WPF application that will communicate with the web server.
I want the WPF application to do the same as the web front-end: Use the web api endpoints after being authenticated with Google. The connection between the WPF application and my web server is done through an HttpClient.

My problem is I don't know how to authenticate that HttpClient connection between the WPF app and the web server.

I tried using the same `Challenge` endpoint but the response I get is of course the HTML from the Google Sign-In page, so I guess I can't use that with an HttpClient...

I also tried authenticating with GoogleApis from the WPF app and use the authenticated token to set cookies in the `HttpClient` but apparently this is not compatible.

**How to authenticate an HttpClient connection to a web api with an external provider such as Google?**

Comment: You can use `WebBrowser` or `WebView` control to display an html content from the Google Sign-In page

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks, I tried that also but got stuck when trying to transfer the authentication cookies from the `WebBrowser` to the `HttpClient`. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: you can try to manage the authentication in WPF application using `WebBrowser` only, without `HttpClient`. `WebBrowser` will manage all cookies internally, since it has the usual IE under the hood

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes but I cannot (should not?) use the WebBrowser to do the web api requests in order to maintain the state inside the WPF ViewModels...can(should) I?

Comment: With `WebBrowser` control you can access DOM (through COM interface) and maintain the state. Another option is to use p/invoke to manage cookies between `WebBrowser` and `HttpClient` as it's written in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975576/managing-cookies-in-a-wpf-webbrowser-control)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski That seems hackish to me...there must be a way to do the authentication in a programmatic manner for a web api connection? :S

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321034/wpf-application-authentication-with-google), it might be helpful